# numpy slicing - TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

datafile: [pattern1.ktx](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt05/pattern1.ktx)

```
import numpy as np

data = np.fromfile('pattern1.ktx', dtype=np.byte)

print ('endianness:', hex(data[12:13]))
```

Result:
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Looks simple enough?  I'm not getting it though.  How to fix this?  Thank You.

How about this one?

```
    b = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[12:12+4], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
    print ('endianess:', hex(b))
```

Same error.  How to fix?

Comment: `hex(data[12])`

Comment: ya, that's it, brainfreeze.  Reaching for the coffee just now.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it returns a list for some reason, so have to index it.

```
b = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[12:12+4], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
print ('endianess:', hex(b[0]))
```

Error fixed.